# Google Chart: Labelling Stacked Column Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Based on googleAPI documentation:
 https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart?hl=en

As you can see in "labeling columns" section each column is labeled with a static value. I want to know if it is possible to label a column with a specific value resulting of the sum of all.

```
// Set chart options
     var options = {

         width: 400,
         height: 300,
         calc:????
     };
```

Should i set this "calc" field with a specific function?

[JSFIDDLE: Total Labeling Column](http://jsfiddle.net/U4VFU/)

I can't figure out how can i customize a label with the sum values of each stacked column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `getNumberOfRows()`, `getNumberOfColumns()` and `getValue()` functions to calculate total and set that value instead of string `total`:

```
function drawChart() {
    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        var total = 0;

        for (var j = 1; j < data.getNumberOfColumns() - 2; j++) {
            // console.log(data.getValue(i, j));
            total += data.getValue(i, j);
        }
        data.setValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, '' + total);
    }
...
```

You will have to change or size of chart or size of fonts to get values properly displayed on columns. Labels are displayed correctly.

Comment: I've already figure out, and it is similar to what you have done. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is my answer.. i hope it helps someone with the same issue.

```
 function getValueAt(column, dataTable, row) {
     return dataTable.getFormattedValue(row, column);
 }

 function setLabelTotal(dataTable) {
     //dataTable must have role: annotation
     var SumOfRows = 0;   

     for (var row = 0; row < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
         SumOfRows = 0;
         for (var col = 0; col < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {

             if (dataTable.getColumnType(col) == 'number') {
                 SumOfRows += dataTable.getValue(row, col);
             }
             if(dataTable.getColumnRole(col) == 'annotation')
             {dataTable.setValue(row, col, SumOfRows.toString());}
         }
     }
 }
```

Notice that you must call these methods on main function (e.g. "drawChart").